# MySQL SUM() with three case conditional

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

I have a dataset and I have to perform a SUM() in MySQL but with 3 levels of GROUP BY. I have tried on my own but I can get the result. I have searched here but I have not found any suitable solution. Here is the data...

```
+---------+----------+---------+------+
| dev_id  | skill    | customer| vote |
+---------+----------+---------+------+
|       1 | .Net     | Walmart |    0 |
|       1 | .Net     | Walmart |    1 |
|       1 | .Net     | Walmart |    1 |
|       1 | .Net     | Walmart |    0 |
|       1 | .Net     | Target  |    0 |
|       1 | .Net     | Target  |    1 |
|       1 | .Net     | Target  |    1 |
|       1 | .Net     | Target  |    0 |
|       1 | Python   | Walmart |    0 |
|       1 | Python   | Walmart |    0 |
|       1 | Python   | Walmart |    1 |
|       1 | Python   | Walmart |    0 |
|       1 | Python   | Target  |    0 |
|       1 | Python   | Target  |    0 |
|       2 | .Net     | Walmart |    0 |
|       2 | .Net     | Walmart |    0 |
|       2 | .Net     | Walmart |    0 |
|       2 | .Net     | Walmart |    0 |
|       2 | .Net     | Target  |    0 |
|       2 | .Net     | Target  |    0 |
|       2 | .Net     | Target  |    1 |
|       2 | .Net     | Target  |    0 |
|       2 | Python   | Walmart |    0 |
|       2 | Python   | Walmart |    0 |
|       2 | Python   | Walmart |    0 |
|       2 | Python   | Walmart |    0 |
|       2 | Python   | Target  |    0 |
|       2 | Python   | Target  |    1 |
+---------+----------+---------+------+
```

I need to group by `dev_id`, then by `skill`, then by `customer`, and the `SUM()` the vote. The desire solution is something like this...

```
+---------+----------+---------+-------+
| dev_id  | .Net     | Python  | Count |
+---------+----------+---------+-------+
|       1 | .Net     | Walmart | 2     |
|       1 | .Net     | Target  | 2     |
|       1 | Python   | Walmart | 1     |
|       1 | Python   | Target  | 0     |
|       2 | .Net     | Walmart | 0     |
|       2 | .Net     | Target  | 1     |
|       2 | Python   | Walmart | 0     |
|       2 | Python   | Target  | 1     |
+---------+----------+---------+-------+
```

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: You can group by all three columns at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the query like:

```
select dev_id, skill, customer, sum(vote) as cnt from <table name> group by dev_id, skill, customer;
```

Comment: Thank you for the query. I'm double checking the outcome.

Comment: Yes that's what I need.